# List all system fonts as dictionary. | python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, dictionary, fonts

I want to get all system fonts (inside `c://Windows//Fonts`) as dictionary since I need to differentiate between bold and italic etc. Though when listing the content of the directory via `os.listdir` or in terminal it's not possible to tell which font is what. (or at least in most cases) Further, even if you wanted to iterate through all fonts you could barely tell whether it's the 'regular' font or a variant.

So windows list the folder as follows:

[image: normalexplorerview]

Each of these 'font-folders' looks like (depending on their different styles) :

[image]

Lastly, this is what I get via the list command (unreadable and unusable for most cases):

[image]

So this is the output I wish I could achieve (or similar):

```
path = "C://Windows//Fonts"
# do some magic
dictionary = {
     'Arial':'Regular': 'Arial-Regular.ttf','Bold':'Arial-Bold.ttf',
     'Carlito:'Regular':' 8514fix.fon','Bold':'someweirdotherfile.fon'
}
```

The only things I got so far are the bare installed font names not their filenames.
So if there is any way to either get the content as dictionary or to get the filename of the fonts please be so kind and give me a tip :)

Comment: Say `a` is a font name. How am I to manually find `a`'s file name?

Comment: By iterating through the files and get the font family name i guess. But thats exactly what I cant get working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the best solution is to use [DirecWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/introducing-directwrite) which is the Windows API to manipulate fonts. It doesn'T involve using any hacks to get the information you need.

There is many way to use DirectWrite to get the information you want, but here is the way that is compatible with the maximum version of Windows.

Dependencies:

- [comtypes](https://pypi.org/project/comtypes/)

```py
import ctypes
import json
from pathlib import Path
import time
from comtypes import COMError, GUID, IUnknown, STDMETHOD
from ctypes import WINFUNCTYPE, Structure, byref, c_ubyte, create_unicode_buffer, HRESULT, POINTER, windll, wintypes
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass
from enum import IntEnum, IntFlag
from sys import getwindowsversion
from typing import Dict, List, Set


@dataclass
class FontFace:
    file_path: List[str] # See this link to know why we need a list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161152/when-can-an-idwritefontface-have-more-than-one-file
    face_name: str


@dataclass
class FontFamily:
    family_name: str
    fonts: List[FontFace]


class DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE(IntEnum):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/ne-dwrite-dwrite_factory_type
    DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED = 0
    DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_ISOLATED = 1


class DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS(IntFlag):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/ne-dwrite-dwrite_font_simulations
    DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS_NONE = 0x0000
    DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS_BOLD = 0x0001
    DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS_OBLIQUE = 0x0002

class DWRITE_FONT_FAMILY_MODEL(IntEnum):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/ne-dwrite_3-dwrite_font_family_model
    DWRITE_FONT_FAMILY_MODEL_TYPOGRAPHIC = 0
    DWRITE_FONT_FAMILY_MODEL_WEIGHT_STRETCH_STYLE = 1


class DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_ID(IntEnum):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/ne-dwrite-dwrite_informational_string_id
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_NONE = 0
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_COPYRIGHT_NOTICE = 1
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_VERSION_STRINGS = 2
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_TRADEMARK = 3
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_MANUFACTURER = 4
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_DESIGNER = 5
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_DESIGNER_URL = 6
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_DESCRIPTION = 7
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_FONT_VENDOR_URL = 8
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_LICENSE_DESCRIPTION = 9
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_LICENSE_INFO_URL = 10
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_WIN32_FAMILY_NAMES = 11
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_WIN32_SUBFAMILY_NAMES = 12
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_TYPOGRAPHIC_FAMILY_NAMES = 13
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_TYPOGRAPHIC_SUBFAMILY_NAMES = 14
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_SAMPLE_TEXT = 15
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_FULL_NAME = 16
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_POSTSCRIPT_NAME = 17
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_POSTSCRIPT_CID_NAME = 18
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_WEIGHT_STRETCH_STYLE_FAMILY_NAME = 19
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_DESIGN_SCRIPT_LANGUAGE_TAG = 20
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_SUPPORTED_SCRIPT_LANGUAGE_TAG = 21
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_PREFERRED_FAMILY_NAMES = DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_TYPOGRAPHIC_FAMILY_NAMES
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_PREFERRED_SUBFAMILY_NAMES = DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_TYPOGRAPHIC_SUBFAMILY_NAMES
    DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_WWS_FAMILY_NAME = DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_WEIGHT_STRETCH_STYLE_FAMILY_NAME


class IDWriteFontFileLoader(IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontfileloader
    _iid_ = GUID("{727cad4e-d6af-4c9e-8a08-d695b11caa49}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateStreamFromKey"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader(IDWriteFontFileLoader):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/idwritelocalfontfileloader
    _iid_ = GUID("{b2d9f3ec-c9fe-4a11-a2ec-d86208f7c0a2}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetFilePathLengthFromKey", [wintypes.LPCVOID, wintypes.UINT, POINTER(wintypes.UINT)]),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetFilePathFromKey", [wintypes.LPCVOID, wintypes.UINT, POINTER(wintypes.WCHAR), wintypes.UINT]),
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetLastWriteTimeFromKey"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFontFile(IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontfile
    _iid_ = GUID("{739d886a-cef5-47dc-8769-1a8b41bebbb0}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetReferenceKey", [POINTER(wintypes.LPCVOID), POINTER(wintypes.UINT)]),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetLoader", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFileLoader))]),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "Analyze", [POINTER(wintypes.BOOL), POINTER(wintypes.UINT), POINTER(wintypes.UINT), POINTER(wintypes.UINT)]),
    ]


class IDWriteLocalizedStrings(IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritelocalizedstrings
    _iid_ = GUID("{08256209-099a-4b34-b86d-c22b110e7771}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(wintypes.UINT, "GetCount"),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "FindLocaleName", [POINTER(wintypes.WCHAR), POINTER(wintypes.UINT), POINTER(wintypes.BOOL)]),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetLocaleNameLength", [wintypes.UINT, POINTER(wintypes.UINT)]),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetLocaleName", [wintypes.UINT, POINTER(wintypes.WCHAR), wintypes.UINT]),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetStringLength", [wintypes.UINT, POINTER(wintypes.UINT)]),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetString", [wintypes.UINT, POINTER(wintypes.WCHAR), wintypes.UINT]),
    ]


class IDWriteFontFace(IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontface
    _iid_ = GUID("{5f49804d-7024-4d43-bfa9-d25984f53849}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetType"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetFiles", [POINTER(wintypes.UINT), POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFile))]),
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetIndex"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(wintypes.UINT, "GetSimulations"),
        STDMETHOD(None, "IsSymbolFont"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetMetrics"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetGlyphCount"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetDesignGlyphMetrics"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetGlyphIndices"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "TryGetFontTable"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "ReleaseFontTable"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetGlyphRunOutline"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetRecommendedRenderingMode"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetGdiCompatibleMetrics"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetGdiCompatibleGlyphMetrics"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFont(IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefont
    _iid_ = GUID("{acd16696-8c14-4f5d-877e-fe3fc1d32737}")


class IDWriteFontList(IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontlist
    _iid_ = GUID("{1a0d8438-1d97-4ec1-aef9-a2fb86ed6acb}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontCollection"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(wintypes.UINT, "GetFontCount"),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetFont", [wintypes.UINT, POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFont))]),
    ]


class IDWriteFontFamily(IDWriteFontList):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontfamily
    _iid_ = GUID("{da20d8ef-812a-4c43-9802-62ec4abd7add}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetFamilyNames", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteLocalizedStrings))]),
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetFirstMatchingFont"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetMatchingFonts"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


IDWriteFont._methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetFontFamily", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFamily))]), 
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetWeight"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetStretch"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetStyle"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "IsSymbolFont"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetFaceNames", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteLocalizedStrings))]),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetInformationalStrings", [wintypes.UINT, POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteLocalizedStrings)), POINTER(wintypes.BOOL)]),
        STDMETHOD(wintypes.UINT, "GetSimulations"),
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetMetrics"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "HasCharacter"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "CreateFontFace", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFace))]),
    ]


class IDWriteFontCollection(IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontcollection
    _iid_ = GUID("{a84cee02-3eea-4eee-a827-87c1a02a0fcc}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(wintypes.UINT, "GetFontFamilyCount"),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetFontFamily", [wintypes.UINT, POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontFamily))]),
        STDMETHOD(None, "FindFamilyName"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetFontFromFontFace", [POINTER(IDWriteFontFace), POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFont))]),
    ]


class IDWriteFontCollection1(IDWriteFontCollection):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefontcollection1
    _iid_ = GUID("{53585141-D9F8-4095-8321-D73CF6BD116C}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontSet1"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFontCollection2(IDWriteFontCollection1):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefontcollection2
    _iid_ = GUID("{514039C6-4617-4064-BF8B-92EA83E506E0}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontFamily"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetMatchingFonts"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontFamilyModel"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontSet2"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory(IUnknown):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefactory
    _iid_ = GUID("{b859ee5a-d838-4b5b-a2e8-1adc7d93db48}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetSystemFontCollection1", [POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontCollection)), wintypes.BOOL]),
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomFontCollection"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "RegisterFontCollectionLoader"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "UnregisterFontCollectionLoader"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFileReference"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomFontFileReference"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFace"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateRenderingParams"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateMonitorRenderingParams"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomRenderingParams"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "RegisterFontFileLoader"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "UnregisterFontFileLoader"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateTextFormat"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateTypography"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetGdiInterop"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateTextLayout"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateGdiCompatibleTextLayout"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateEllipsisTrimmingSign"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateTextAnalyzer"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateNumberSubstitution"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateGlyphRunAnalysis"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory1(IDWriteFactory):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_1/nn-dwrite_1-idwritefactory1
    _iid_ = GUID("{30572f99-dac6-41db-a16e-0486307e606a}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetEudcFontCollection"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomRenderingParams1"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory2(IDWriteFactory1):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_2/nn-dwrite_2-idwritefactory2
    _iid_ = GUID("{0439fc60-ca44-4994-8dee-3a9af7b732ec}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetSystemFontFallback"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFallbackBuilder"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "TranslateColorGlyphRun"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomRenderingParams2"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateGlyphRunAnalysis"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory3(IDWriteFactory2):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefactory3
    _iid_ = GUID("{9A1B41C3-D3BB-466A-87FC-FE67556A3B65}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateGlyphRunAnalysis"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateCustomRenderingParams3"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFaceReference"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFaceReference"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetSystemFontSet1"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontSetBuilder"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontCollectionFromFontSet"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetSystemFontCollection2", [wintypes.BOOL, POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontCollection1)), wintypes.BOOL]),
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetFontDownloadQueue"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory4(IDWriteFactory3):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefactory4
    _iid_ = GUID("{4B0B5BD3-0797-4549-8AC5-FE915CC53856}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "TranslateColorGlyphRun"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "ComputeGlyphOrigins"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "ComputeGlyphOrigins"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory5(IDWriteFactory4):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefactory5
    _iid_ = GUID("{958DB99A-BE2A-4F09-AF7D-65189803D1D3}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontSetBuilder"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateInMemoryFontFileLoader"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateHttpFontFileLoader"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "AnalyzeContainerType"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "UnpackFontFile"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class IDWriteFactory6(IDWriteFactory5):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nn-dwrite_3-idwritefactory6
    _iid_ = GUID("{F3744D80-21F7-42EB-B35D-995BC72FC223}")
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontFaceReference"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontResource"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "GetSystemFontSet2"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, "GetSystemFontCollection3", [wintypes.BOOL, wintypes.UINT, POINTER(POINTER(IDWriteFontCollection2))]),
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontCollectionFromFontSet"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateFontSetBuilder"),  # Need to be implemented
        STDMETHOD(None, "CreateTextFormat"),  # Need to be implemented
    ]


class Kernel32:
    def __init__(self):
        kernel32 = windll.kernel32

        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlocalename
        self.GetUserDefaultLocaleName = kernel32.GetUserDefaultLocaleName
        self.GetUserDefaultLocaleName.restype = wintypes.INT
        self.GetUserDefaultLocaleName.argtypes = [wintypes.LPWSTR, wintypes.INT]
        self.GetUserDefaultLocaleName.errcheck = self.errcheck_is_result_0

        self.LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH = 85


    def GetUserDefaultLocaleNameFunc(self) -> str:
        locale_buffer = create_unicode_buffer(self.LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
        try:
            self.GetUserDefaultLocaleName(locale_buffer, self.LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
        except ValueError:
            return "en-us"

        return locale_buffer.value


    @staticmethod
    def errcheck_is_result_0(result, func, args):
        if result == 0:
            raise ValueError(f"Error encountered with {func.__name__}.")
        return result


class DirectWrite:
    def __init__(self):
        dwrite = windll.dwrite

        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-dwritecreatefactory
        self.DWriteCreateFactory = dwrite.DWriteCreateFactory
        self.DWriteCreateFactory.restype = HRESULT
        self.DWriteCreateFactory.argtypes = [wintypes.UINT, GUID, POINTER(POINTER(IUnknown))]


    def get_str_from_localized_strings(self, localized_strings) -> str:
        # From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritelocalizedstrings#remarks

        kernel32 = Kernel32()
        locale_name = kernel32.GetUserDefaultLocaleNameFunc()

        index = wintypes.UINT()
        exists = wintypes.BOOL()
        localized_strings.FindLocaleName(locale_name, byref(index), byref(exists))

        if not exists:
            localized_strings.FindLocaleName("en-us", byref(index), byref(exists))

        if not exists:
            index = 0

        length = wintypes.UINT()
        localized_strings.GetStringLength(index, byref(length))

        localized_strings_buffer = create_unicode_buffer(length.value + 1)
        localized_strings.GetString(index, localized_strings_buffer, len(localized_strings_buffer))

        return localized_strings_buffer.value


class WindowsVersionHelpers:
    @staticmethod
    def is_windows_version_or_greater(windows_version, major: int, minor: int, build: int) -> bool:
        """
        Parameters:
            windows_version: An object from getwindowsversion.
            major (int): The minimum major OS version number.
            minor (int): The minimum minor OS version number.
            build (int): The minimum build version number.
        Returns:
            True if the specified version matches or if it is greater than the version of the current Windows OS. Otherwise, False.
        """

        if windows_version.major > major:
            return True
        elif windows_version.major == major and windows_version.minor > minor:
            return True
        else:
            return (
                windows_version.major == major
                and windows_version.minor == minor
                and windows_version.build >= build
            )

    @staticmethod
    def is_windows_vista_sp2_or_greater(windows_version) -> bool:
        # From https://www.lifewire.com/windows-version-numbers-2625171
        return WindowsVersionHelpers.is_windows_version_or_greater(windows_version, 6, 0, 6002)
    
    @staticmethod
    def is_windows_fall_creators_update_or_greater(windows_version) -> bool:
        # From https://www.lifewire.com/windows-version-numbers-2625171
        return WindowsVersionHelpers.is_windows_version_or_greater(windows_version, 10, 0, 16299)


def get_file_path_from_IDWriteFontFace(font_face: POINTER(IDWriteFontFace)) -> List[str]:
    face_file_path = []

    file_count = wintypes.UINT()
    font_face.GetFiles(byref(file_count), None)

    font_files = (POINTER(IDWriteFontFile) * file_count.value)()
    font_face.GetFiles(byref(file_count), font_files)

    for font_file in font_files:
        font_file_reference_key = wintypes.LPCVOID()
        font_file_reference_key_size = wintypes.UINT()
        font_file.GetReferenceKey(byref(font_file_reference_key), byref(font_file_reference_key_size))

        loader = POINTER(IDWriteFontFileLoader)()
        font_file.GetLoader(byref(loader))

        local_loader = loader.QueryInterface(IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader)

        is_supported_font_type = wintypes.BOOL()
        font_file_type = wintypes.UINT()
        font_face_type = wintypes.UINT()
        number_of_faces = wintypes.UINT()
        font_file.Analyze(byref(is_supported_font_type), byref(font_file_type), byref(font_face_type), byref(number_of_faces))

        path_len = wintypes.UINT()
        local_loader.GetFilePathLengthFromKey(font_file_reference_key, font_file_reference_key_size, byref(path_len))

        buffer = create_unicode_buffer(path_len.value + 1)
        local_loader.GetFilePathFromKey(font_file_reference_key, font_file_reference_key_size, buffer, len(buffer))

        face_file_path.append(str(Path(buffer.value).resolve()))
    
    return face_file_path


def get_system_fonts_families_simulate_gdi() -> List[FontFamily]:
    """
    It use the [RBIZ font family model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/font-selection#rbiz-font-family-model)
    This method only simulates how GDI works. In some case, the result may be different from GDI.
    """
    windows_version = getwindowsversion()

    if not WindowsVersionHelpers.is_windows_vista_sp2_or_greater(windows_version):
        raise OSError("This program only works on Windows Vista SP2 or more")

    dwrite = DirectWrite()
    fonts_families: Dict[str, FontFamily] = {}

    dwrite_factory = POINTER(IDWriteFactory)()
    dwrite.DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE.DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_ISOLATED, dwrite_factory._iid_, byref(dwrite_factory))

    sys_collection = POINTER(IDWriteFontCollection)()
    dwrite_factory.GetSystemFontCollection1(byref(sys_collection), False)

    for i in range(sys_collection.GetFontFamilyCount()):
        family = POINTER(IDWriteFontFamily)()
        sys_collection.GetFontFamily(i, byref(family))

        for j in range(family.GetFontCount()):
            try:
                font = POINTER(IDWriteFont)()
                family.GetFont(j, byref(font))
            except COMError:
                # If the file doesn't exist, DirectWrite raise an exception
                continue

            simulations = font.GetSimulations()
            if simulations != DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS.DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS_NONE:
                continue

            family_names = POINTER(IDWriteLocalizedStrings)()
            exists = wintypes.BOOL()
            font.GetInformationalStrings(DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_ID.DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_WIN32_FAMILY_NAMES, byref(family_names), byref(exists))
            family_names_str = dwrite.get_str_from_localized_strings(family_names)
            if not exists:
                raise ValueError("Could not fetch the family names")

            if family_names_str in fonts_families:
                font_familie = fonts_families[family_names_str]
            else:
                font_familie = FontFamily(family_names_str, [])
                fonts_families[family_names_str] = font_familie

            face_name = POINTER(IDWriteLocalizedStrings)()
            exists = wintypes.BOOL()
            font.GetInformationalStrings(DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_ID.DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_WIN32_SUBFAMILY_NAMES, byref(face_name), byref(exists))
            face_name_str = dwrite.get_str_from_localized_strings(face_name)
            if not exists:
                raise ValueError("Could not fetch the family names")
            
            font_face = POINTER(IDWriteFontFace)()
            font.CreateFontFace(byref(font_face))

            face_file_path = get_file_path_from_IDWriteFontFace(font_face)

            font_familie.fonts.append(FontFace(face_file_path, face_name_str))
    return fonts_families.values()


def get_system_fonts_families_WWS() -> List[FontFamily]:
    """
    It use the [Weight-stretch-style font family model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/font-selection#weight-stretch-style-font-family-model)
    """
    windows_version = getwindowsversion()

    if not WindowsVersionHelpers.is_windows_vista_sp2_or_greater(windows_version):
        raise OSError("This program only works on Windows Vista SP2 or more")

    dwrite = DirectWrite()
    fonts_families: List[FontFamily] = []

    dwrite_factory = POINTER(IDWriteFactory)()
    dwrite.DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE.DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_ISOLATED, dwrite_factory._iid_, byref(dwrite_factory))

    sys_collection = POINTER(IDWriteFontCollection)()
    dwrite_factory.GetSystemFontCollection1(byref(sys_collection), False)

    for i in range(sys_collection.GetFontFamilyCount()):
        family = POINTER(IDWriteFontFamily)()
        sys_collection.GetFontFamily(i, byref(family))

        family_names = POINTER(IDWriteLocalizedStrings)()
        family.GetFamilyNames(byref(family_names))
        family_names_str = dwrite.get_str_from_localized_strings(family_names)

        faces: List[FontFace] = []
        for j in range(family.GetFontCount()):
            try:
                font = POINTER(IDWriteFont)()
                family.GetFont(j, byref(font))
            except COMError:
                # If the file doesn't exist, DirectWrite raise an exception
                continue

            simulations = font.GetSimulations()
            if simulations != DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS.DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS_NONE:
                continue

            face_name = POINTER(IDWriteLocalizedStrings)()
            font.GetFaceNames(byref(face_name))
            face_name_str = dwrite.get_str_from_localized_strings(face_name)

            font_face = POINTER(IDWriteFontFace)()
            font.CreateFontFace(byref(font_face))

            face_file_path = get_file_path_from_IDWriteFontFace(font_face)

            faces.append(FontFace(face_file_path, face_name_str))
        fonts_families.append(FontFamily(family_names_str, faces))
    return fonts_families


def get_system_fonts_families_typographic_model() -> List[FontFamily]:
    """
    It use the [Typographic font family model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/font-selection#typographic-font-family-model)
    """
    windows_version = getwindowsversion()

    if not WindowsVersionHelpers.is_windows_fall_creators_update_or_greater(windows_version):
        raise OSError("This program only works on Windows 10 Fall Creators Update or more")

    dwrite = DirectWrite()
    fonts_families: List[FontFamily] = []

    dwrite_factory = POINTER(IDWriteFactory6)()
    dwrite.DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE.DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_ISOLATED, dwrite_factory._iid_, byref(dwrite_factory))

    sys_collection = POINTER(IDWriteFontCollection2)()
    dwrite_factory.GetSystemFontCollection3(False, DWRITE_FONT_FAMILY_MODEL.DWRITE_FONT_FAMILY_MODEL_TYPOGRAPHIC, byref(sys_collection))

    for i in range(sys_collection.GetFontFamilyCount()):
        family = POINTER(IDWriteFontFamily)()
        sys_collection.GetFontFamily(i, byref(family))

        family_names = POINTER(IDWriteLocalizedStrings)()
        family.GetFamilyNames(byref(family_names))
        family_names_str = dwrite.get_str_from_localized_strings(family_names)

        faces: List[FontFace] = []
        for j in range(family.GetFontCount()):
            try:
                font = POINTER(IDWriteFont)()
                family.GetFont(j, byref(font))
            except COMError:
                # If the file doesn't exist, DirectWrite raise an exception
                continue

            simulations = font.GetSimulations()
            if simulations != DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS.DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS_NONE:
                continue

            face_file_path: List[Path] = []

            face_name = POINTER(IDWriteLocalizedStrings)()
            font.GetFaceNames(byref(face_name))
            face_name_str = dwrite.get_str_from_localized_strings(face_name)

            font_face = POINTER(IDWriteFontFace)()
            font.CreateFontFace(byref(font_face))

            face_file_path = get_file_path_from_IDWriteFontFace(font_face)

            faces.append(FontFace(face_file_path, face_name_str))
        fonts_families.append(FontFamily(family_names_str, faces))
    return fonts_families


def main():
    # use get_system_fonts_families_simulate_gdi, get_system_fonts_families_WWS or get_system_fonts_families_typographic_model
    font_families = get_system_fonts_families_simulate_gdi() 

    font_families_dict = [asdict(font_family) for font_family in get_system_fonts_families_simulate_gdi()]
    json_string = json.dumps(font_families_dict, indent=4)
    print(json_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome thank you so much. I reckon DirectWrite does not have the 4 variant limitations like GDI that's why it groups all together (Like all Arials including narrow etc). Is there a way to split it with DirectWrite similar to GDI?

Comment: From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/font-selection#rbiz-font-family-model), it says *DirectWrite does not directly support the RBIZ font family model, but it does provide methods of converting to and from the RBIZ model*, so I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Yeah I only Found IDWriteFontSet4 but I don't quite get how to use it  hoped for an easy solution but I guess Its trial and error then. Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: I found a way to list the font has the RBIZ model. I edited my answer.

Comment: Man you are some kind of wizard. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 2):

I know that you made that post 2 years ago, but so happens that I made piece of code that makes similar thing for which you're asking for. I'm into programming only 1,5 months (and it's my 1st answer on stackoverflow ever), so probably it can be improved in many ways, but maybe there will be some guy, which I'll help with that code or give idea how they'll write it.

```
from fontTools import ttLib
import os
from os import walk
import json

path = "C://Windows//Fonts"

fonts_path = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(fr'{path}\Windows\Fonts'):
    for i in filenames:
        if any(i.endswith(ext) for ext in ['.ttf', '.otf', '.ttc', '.ttz', '.woff', '.woff2']):
            fonts_path.append(dirpath.replace('\\\\', '\\') + '\\' + i)

def getFont(font, font_path):
    x = lambda x: font['name'].getDebugName(x)
    if x(16) is None:
        return x(1), x(2), font_path
    if x(16) is not None:
        return x(16), x(17), font_path
    else:
        pass

fonts = []

for i in range(len(fonts_path)):
        j = fonts_path[i]
        if not j.endswith('.ttc'):
            fonts.append(getFont(ttLib.TTFont(j), j))
        if j.endswith('.ttc'):
            try:
                for k in range(100):
                    fonts.append(getFont(ttLib.TTFont(j, fontNumber=k), j))
            except:
                pass

fonts_dict = {}

no_dups = []
for i in fonts:
    index_0 = i[0]
    if index_0 not in no_dups:
        no_dups.append(index_0)

for i in fonts:
    for k in no_dups:
        if i[0] == k:
            fonts_dict[k] = json.loads('{\"' + str(i[1]) + '\" : \"' + str(i[2]).split('\\')[-1] + '\"}')
            for j in fonts:
                if i[0] == j[0]:
                    fonts_dict[k][j[1]] = j[2].split('\\')[-1]

print(json.dumps(fonts_dict, indent=2))
```

**Some sample output** (I made it shorter, because otherwise it'd be too big):

```
{
 "CAC Moose PL": {
    "Regular": "CAC Moose PL.otf"
  },
  "Calibri": {
    "Bold Italic": "calibriz.ttf",
    "Regular": "calibri.ttf",
    "Bold": "calibrib.ttf",
    "Italic": "calibrii.ttf",
    "Light": "calibril.ttf",
    "Light Italic": "calibrili.ttf"
  },
  "Cambria": {
    "Bold Italic": "cambriaz.ttf",
    "Regular": "cambria.ttc",
    "Bold": "cambriab.ttf",
    "Italic": "cambriai.ttf"
  },
  "Cambria Math": {
    "Regular": "cambria.ttc"
  },
  "Candara": {
    "Bold Italic": "Candaraz.ttf",
    "Regular": "Candara.ttf",
    "Bold": "Candarab.ttf",
    "Italic": "Candarai.ttf",
    "Light": "Candaral.ttf",
    "Light Italic": "Candarali.ttf"
  },
  "Capibara Mono B PL": {
    "Regular": "Capibara Mono B PL.otf"
  }
}
```

If someone needs full path to the font, then the only thing you need to change is removing .split('\')[-1] in last for loop, then output will be like that:

```
  "Arial": {
    "Black": "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ariblk.ttf",
    "Regular": "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf",
    "Bold": "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialbd.ttf",
    "Bold Italic": "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialbi.ttf",
    "Italic": "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ariali.ttf"
  }
```

Some **postscriptium**. Fonts in Windows are stored in two folders. One for global fonts (installed for all users) and user's specific. Global fonts are stored in 'C:\Windows\Fonts' but user local are stored in 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts', so keep that in mind. It's possible to simply take username to variable by `os.getlogin()`.

I decided to ignore .fon fonts because they're very problematic (for me).

**Some code explaination:**

```
fonts_path = []

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(fr'{path}\Windows\Fonts'):
    for i in filenames:
        if any(i.endswith(ext) for ext in ['.ttf', '.otf', '.ttc', '.ttz', '.woff', '.woff2']):
            fonts_path.append(dirpath.replace('\\\\', '\\') + '\\' + i)
```

Taking only .ttf, otf, ttc, ttz, woff and woff2 fonts from Windows's global fonts folder and making list (fonts_path) with all fonts path.

```
def getFont(font, font_path):
    x = lambda x: font['name'].getDebugName(x)
    if x(16) is None:
        return x(1), x(2), font_path
    if x(16) is not None:
        return x(16), x(17), font_path
    else:
        pass
```

So this funtion based on ttLib.TTFont file obtained in `ttLib.TTFont(font_path)` function from fontTools library and font path, checks debug names of fonts. Debug names are pre-defined metadata of font and contains informations such as font name, font family etc. You can read about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name#name-ids. So example use for full font name'll be:

```
NameID = 4
font = ttLib.TTFont(font_path)
font_full_name = font['name'].getDebugName(NameID)
print(font_full_name)
```

`Example output: Candara Bold Italic`

Basicly we need only family font name and  font name. Only problem is that some fonts are having `None` value on NameID 1 and 2 so based on font, value is taken from NameID 1, 2 or 16, 17. After that every font is being packed to tuple in this way: (font_family, font_name, font_path)

```
fonts = []

for i in range(len(fonts_path)):
        j = fonts_path[i]
        if not j.endswith('.ttc'):
            fonts.append(getFont(ttLib.TTFont(j), j))
        if j.endswith('.ttc'):
            try:
                for k in range(100):
                    fonts.append(getFont(ttLib.TTFont(j, fontNumber=k), j))
            except:
                pass
```

.ttc fonts need special treatment, because .ttc font format contains more than one font, so we must specify which font we're going to use, so syntax of `ttLib.TTFont(font_path)` needs one more argument: `fontNumber`, so then it become: `ttLib.TTFont(font_path, fontNumber=font_index)`.

After that we have list full of tuples in order: (font_family, font_name, font_path)

```
no_dups = []
for i in fonts:
    index_0 = i[0]
    if index_0 not in no_dups:
        no_dups.append(index_0)
```

We make list (named: no_dups) of all font families (stored in index 0 of tuple), without duplications.

```
fonts_dict = {}

for i in fonts:
    for k in no_dups:
        if i[0] == k:
            fonts_dict[k] = json.loads('{\"' + str(i[1]) + '\" : \"' + str(i[2]).split('\\')[-1] + '\"}')
            for j in fonts:
                if i[0] == j[0]:
                    fonts_dict[k][j[1]] = j[2].split('\\')[-1]
```

This code creates all font families as dictionary and then changes value in that way that value of font family dict is another dict.
So it's manipulated in this way:

1. It's in list:

   `[..., 'Cambria', ...]`
2. Making dict with one value at time:

   `{...}, "Cambria": {"Bold Italic": "calibriz.ttf"}, {...}`
3. Adding more key's with values to subdicts:

   `{...}, "Cambria": {"Bold Italic": "calibriz.ttf", "Regular": "cambria.ttc"}, {...}`

And it's doing it till everything is assigned to dictionary.

And lastly:

```
 print(json.dumps(fonts_dict, indent=2))
```

Printing result in nicely formated way.

Hope that I'll help somebody.

Comment: My comment seems to be removed for whatever reason - Anyways: Thank you very much! The code looks great and helps me and others a lot! Good work!